# Как завершить сессию в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii, cookie, сессия

Как завершить сессию для администратора в yii2, чтобы его попросило заново вводить пароль?
Я сменил пароль, но если до этого вошли - админ остается в кабинете.

Answer (score 0):

Сессия это файл, можно удалить его с сервера и пользователя разлогинить так как не найдется по ключу авторизации хранившегося в cookie файла с такой сессией (ну или если вы храните сессии в БД или оперативной памяти то нужно от туда удалить данные про эту сессию).

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ.

```
foreach(glob(ini_get("session.save_path") . "/*") as $sessionFile) {
    unlink($sessionFile);
}
```